# Reset the value after a loop ends

Tags: c, loops

I want `n` to be reset to its first value entered by user.

For example I enter 3 and program wants me to enter 3 numbers to be added up. However when `n` is iterated by the end of for loop it is set to zero.

When I print `n` out I want it to be seen as 3 which is original value given by user. As it stays 0 I also can't find the average of these numbers since sum / 0 is unknown.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int sum=0;
    int n;
    int entered=0;
    printf("How many numbers to be summed up:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(;n>0;n--){
        printf("Enter the number to be summed up:");
        scanf("%d",&entered);
        sum+= entered;
    }
    printf("Number of Entries:%d\nSum of the Entered numbers:%d",n,sum);
    printf("Average:%d",sum/n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use some other variable as loop iterator; `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Comment: @kiranBiradar You should post that as the answer imo

Comment: Another way (though less *conventional* than that suggested by @kiran) is simply to have another variable to save the 'original' value of n. If we declare it as `int saved;` and have (between the `scanf` and `for` statements): `saved = n;` we can then get the average by using `sum/saved` instead of `sum/n`.

Comment: @Martin I'm trying to find good duplicate but not finding one. Which explains from basic.

Comment: for (i=0;i<n;i++) have solved my problem. Thank you all for taking your time. Have a nice day!

Comment: Note that is is always an error not to test the return value from scanf().